# How can I get my spreadsheet to re-run my custom functions if a cell in the sheet containing a parameter of the function was edited?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a function called "getStartTime". Uses an employee's name and the date of their shift to input their start time when they are clocked in on the sheet. These are recorded in sort of an employee scorecard, and I want the times in their card to update if they are edited for any reason. All of the employees are stored in one sheet, so there is no fixed range where they might line up. (sorted alphabetically, new hires or terminated employees can change this order. Here's the code for my onEdit trigger:

```
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  
  // Get the coordinates of the edited range
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  
  // Get the coordinates of the data range
  var dataRangeStartRow = dataRange.getRow();
  var dataRangeStartColumn = dataRange.getColumn();
  var dataRangeEndRow = dataRange.getLastRow(); 
  var dataRangeEndColumn = dataRange.getLastColumn();
  
  // Check if the edited range intersects with the data range
  if (editedRow >= dataRangeStartRow && editedRow <= dataRangeEndRow &&
    editedColumn >= dataRangeStartColumn && editedColumn <= dataRangeEndColumn) {
    let formulas = dataRange.getFormulas();
    for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < formulas[i].length; j++) {
        let formula = formulas[i][j];
        // Check if the cell contains a formula and if the formula contains "getStartTime"
        if (formula && formula.indexOf("getStartTime") !== -1) {
           // Update the formula to force a recalculation
           var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1);
           cell.clearContent();
           Utilities.sleep(100);
           cell.setFormula(formula);
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I thought it would find any instance of the formula "getStartTime", clear it, then reapply it to recalculate or refresh the value. Nothing usually happens, but it often works once after I edit the function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/tour
Any specific reason why you have named the function "onEditTrigger" and not "onEdit"?
Here's the list for simple triggers and the function name should be "onEdit" as per this - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're attempting to trigger a recalculation of the "getStartTime" function by clearing and reapplying the formula when any edit is made on the sheet. However, there might be a more straightforward approach to achieve what you want without manually manipulating formulas.

Instead of trying to force a recalculation of the "getStartTime" function, you can use the `onEdit` trigger to call the "getStartTime" function directly whenever an edit is made in the sheet. This way, the function will be executed again, and the start time will be recalculated automatically.

Here's how you can modify your `onEditTrigger` function to achieve this:

```js
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  
  // Check if the edit is within the range where "getStartTime" function is used
  if (sheet.getName() == "YourSheetName" && editedColumn == yourColumnNumber) {
    // Call the "getStartTime" function for the edited row
    getStartTime(editedRow);
  }
}
```

Replace "YourSheetName" with the name of your sheet and "yourColumnNumber" with the column number where the "getStartTime" function is used.

With this approach, whenever an edit is made in the specified column, the "getStartTime" function will be called for the corresponding row, ensuring that the start time is recalculated automatically. You don't need to manually clear and reapply formulas.